# GeoServer GetFeatureInfo request property ordering

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I am attempting to transition from text/HTML to application/JSON info_format in my GetFeatureInfo requests.  The issue I'm running into is that when I use a GetFeatureInfo request with a PostgreSQL view the properties are returned in alphabetical order as opposed to the ordering specified in the view.  This is not the case when I use GetFeatureInfo on a table or when I use the text/HTML info_format on a PostgreSQL view.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: You really can't control the order without an ORDER BY in the query. The result set is unordered, and therefore equivalent. If you need a specific order, can't you apply it afterwards?

Comment: I suppose that the question is not about ordering the features but the attributes `geometry, attr_1, attr_2` vs. `geometry, attr_2, attr_1`.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about ordering the properties not the features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an artefact of the way the JSON code loops over the attributes, however since you are expected to do something with the returned JSON it doesn't really matter what order it is returned in.

If it is absolutely essential to have a fixed order (i.e. you have a very dumb client) then you can write a [FreeMarker template](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/geojson.html) to enforce it.

Comment: This looks like it will work, thanks.  The client is very dumb on purpose (I prefer to think of it as generic) so that I can specify which fields to include as well as the ordering of the fields with views at the database level.